# Making a 'menu' where you can search 'movie' by name, genre, year, etc

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a school project, where I gotta make a function which can be used for a searching movies by name, genre, year, etc. I made a menu where you can choose between commands like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, or 7 for name, genre, lasting, director, lead role, country, year. Now, I need to make function where you can, for example, choose 1 (name) so you can search for the movie by entering the name and as a result you will get (One flew over cuckoo's nest|Drama|133|Milos Forman|Jack Nicholson|USA|1975). 
I began with something like this:

```
def name():
    f = open("svi.txt","r")
    l = []

    for x in f.readlines():
        n = x.strip().split("|")
        name_m = n[0]
        l.append(name_m)
```

If this is right way, what should I do next? 
And by the way, all movies are saved in my txt file.

Comment: For clarification, the name function above is what occurs when the command `1` for name is chosen, correct?

Comment: Do you really think reading the text file, splitting fields has anything to do with search by name? Don't you have to do this regardless of your search criteria? If so, it makes more sense to put these functionality in a common place. And then perform relevant search. In the future, possibly you will query a database, rather than a txt file. In that case, depending on the search criteria, you will only need to change the where clause of your SQL statement.

Comment: @dimwittedanimal yes, i will import this function in that menu, i thought i should make 7 functions for every part of movie and then import all of them into the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right way , though there are many better ways , but you should first learn it to do it your way! Now the function name should have an input argument (which would be the search term entered by the user) and then that name should be searched in the list of names you just created ('l'). Then you have to obtain the index of the movie name in list 'l' and finally return the element at the obtained index from a list made like:

```
`f.read().split()[index]`
```

The piece of code below is for  name function:

```
def name(movie_name):
    f = open("svi.txt","r")
    l = []

    for x in f.readlines():
        n = x.strip().split("|")
        name_m = n[0]
        l.append(name_m)
    index = 0
    if movie_name in l:
        index = l.index(movie_name)
    else:
        print("Error movie name not found")
        return
    z = f.read().split('\n')
    print("Here are the movie details:")
    print(z[index])
    return
```

One of the neat ways to do this would be like:

```
def name(movie_name):
    with open("svi.txt",'r') as fh:
        file = fh.read()
        fh.close()
    names = [ i.split('|')[0] for i in file.split('\n') ]
    try:
        return (file.split('\n')[names.index(movie_name)])
    except:
        return ("Name not found! No records of this movie!")
```

Now call the function as:

`>>> print(name('One flew over cuckoo\'s nest'))`

Comment: if you can, I will be grateful.

Comment: or if you have some better way, u can also type that, I need help anyway

Comment: I dont understand parameter "movie_name" part, when i call this function in menu it says movie_name not defined, I don't understand this, sorry im new in this

Comment: but let me try it again

Comment: Movie name is the name of the movie entered by you , (say iron man) , it's supposed to be an input!

Comment: should i type name of a movie there or what?

Comment: I have edited the code , just run it directly , make sure you have svi.txt in the same folder as the python program file.

Comment: instead of in parameter i went 
movie_name = input("Enter movie name: "))

but when I enter  either right or wrong it always says that movie doesnt exist?

Comment: leave it , i'll make bogus test data

Comment: Run the function and then call it , i have modified it again see the code !

Answer (score 0):

If a line in your text file is like `line = "One flew over cuckoo's nest|Drama|133|Milos Forman|Jack Nicholson|USA|1975"`, doing `line.strip().split("|")[0]` gives you `"One flew over cuckoo's nest"`.

I would rewrite the `name()` function using `with` statement as it takes care of closing the file.

```
def name(filename): 
    with open(filename) as f:
        movies = [line.strip().split("|")[0] for line in f]

    return movies

print(name("svi.txt"))
```

[Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) says:

> It is good practice to use the [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) keyword when dealing with file objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point.